# Permission denied trying to access file owned by root

Tags: ansible

I have 2 remote servers, and I need to transfer files from one server to another using `synchronize` directive.

In serverA I created an SSH key (id_rsa) using the sudo user, and copied the public key into serverB (into authorized_keys file of the same sudo user).

Hosts file

```
[servers]
prod_server ansible_host=IP_prod
new_server ansible_host=IP_new

[servers:vars]
ansible_user=sudo_user
ansible_sudo_pass=sudo_password
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Play

```
- name: Transfer files from prod to new server
  hosts: new_server
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
  - rsync
```

Task

```
- name: Copy files to new server
  synchronize:
    src: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
    dest: /opt
  delegate_to: prod_server
```

When running the playbook an error shows up:

`change_dir \"/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld\" failed: Permission denied`
That means that the `sudo_user` don't have root privileges to access that file.
And if I set `become: true` it would be possible to access the `fullchain.pem` file, but the play will try then to transfer the file using the root user, and the SSH key `id_rsa` is owned by the `sudo_user`

What do I have to set to make this work?

Comment: Connect as root or escalate privilege, don't delegate, use an rsync uri as `dest` with the correct username

Comment: To connect as root, that means that my laptop SSH key must be present in both remote servers, in root user's authorized_keys file, and currently my laptop SSH key is only present in the remote sudo user account.
If I escalate privilege with ```become: true``` there's the problem of the remote SSH key owned only by the ```sudo user```...
Maybe I'm missing something?
Could you give me an example of "use an rsync uri as ```dest``` with the correct username"?

Comment: The synchronize documentation page has the most complete list of examples I can think of

Comment: You mean this? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#examples
Unfortunately there's nothing about rsync uri as dest with the correct username....
Merci quand même !

Comment: Instead here's a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1147800/permission-denied-in-ansible-synchronize-module
and the solution suggested ```rsync_path: sudo rsync``` seems the right direction!

Comment: However using ```rsync_path: sudo rsync```, a further error shows up:
```nsudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper```

Answer (score 0):

If you  can "sudo su - " on the remote box and are using -b (become)..

synchronize:
src: /your local directory path
dest: /path on remote host owned by root
rsync_path: "sudo rsync"
mode: push